# fine-tuning an efficentnet_lite1 model with tflite model maker

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, transfer-learning, data-augmentation

i am fine-tuning an efficentnet_lite1 model to train it on my own data using tflite model maker:

```
spec = model_spec.get("efficientdet_lite1")
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=2, train_whole_model=True, epochs=1, validation_data=val_data)
```

there seems like there is a data augmentations applied to my data when training (probably a random horizontal flip ) which i don't want
how can I disable all augmentations done by default

I tried to look for the config file which is easily found when fine-tuning the traditional way but when using the model make there is no model actually downloaded or i am not able to find it